# Turbo Stream Rails does not update page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

I am new to Ruby on Rails and need help with figuring out how Turbo Stream works in Rails.
I did everything by tutorials, however, the content of the page was not updating. I decided to test how Turbo Stream will behave on simple div.

In `index.html.erb` file I created such div with `id="test"`:

```
<div id = "test">Hallow</div>
```

In the same file I am creating a button that calls method `refresh` in controller.

```
<%=button_to " ", refresh_path(:task => task, format: :turbo_stream)%>
```

The method is called and works properly, I have already checked it without Turbo Stream.

The content of `refresh.turbo_stream.erb`:

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace 'test', partial: 'refresh' %>
```

The content of `_refresh.html.erb`

```
<h1>GoodBye</h1>
```

Here is the proof that Turbo Stream works
[image: as turbo stream]

Indeed Turbo Stream renders the page, but I get such an output.
[image: This is the output I get]

I tried writing respond in controller, deleting turbo_stream format (it caused another error), playing with routes, but did not come up to anything.

I am sorry if this question might have been answered already, but I tried different options and nothing worked for me. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turbo* doesn't process links with formats other than html ([apparently](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.2.4/src/core/url.ts#L28) *php* as well).

So when you click a link or a button, that has ".json", ".xml", or ".turbo_stream" or anything else, *Turbo* gives up and just sends you [directly](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.2.4/src/core/drive/navigator.ts#L30) to that page where browser displays it the best it can, and it knows nothing about what to do with *turbo_stream*, which has `Content-Type: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html`, so, plain text in the browser.

To fix it, remove `:format`:

```
<%= button_to "refresh", refresh_path(task: task) %>
```

With this button, *Turbo* will send a correct request, where it will wait for html or turbo_stream response, which you can see in the request header:
`Accept: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html, text/html, application/xhtml+xml`

If the server then responds with *turbo_stream* format: `Content-Type: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html` then stream instructions will execute on the current page. There are other rules, but one step at a time.

To render an appropriate response use `respond_to` method in your controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html         { render :page } # renders `page.html.erb`
  format.turbo_stream { render :page } # renders `page.turbo_stream.erb`
  # or render <turbo-stream> inline
  # format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace :test, partial: "test_partial" }
end
```